# How to execute a function in MongoDB Shell?

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, function, mongo-shell

I have a MongoDB function to Insert some data from 1 Doc to another Doc as below, I don't know if it's right or wrong but now I just want to find a way to test it on MongoDB Shell.

```
function loadEducation() {
        const bulkInsert = db.education.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        const documents = db.summaryData.find({});

        documents.forEach(function (doc) {
            const element = {
                education: "$doc.education", 
                "education_num": "$doc.education_num"
            };
            bulkInsert.find(element).upsert().replaceOne(element);
        });
        bulkInsert.execute();
        return true;
        }
```

I've read many posts on the internet but non of them work. For example:

1. I've already insert the function into `db.system.js`, but I can't use `db.loadServerScripts()` because the error "`db.loadServerScripts is not a function`"
2. `db.eval("loadEducation()")` won't work too. The same error as above "`db.eval is not a function`"

There are many posts about this kind of problem on the internet (StackOverflow too) but there is no answer at all. For example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72224708/trying-to-call-function-by-using-db-evalfunctionname-in-mongodb-compass-ve) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73477063/db-loadserverscripts-from-mongodb-shell) and [here](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/functions-implementation-and-understanding/15150/2)

Comment: I think you can do the same with a simple aggregation pipeline, i.e. you don't need bulkInsert

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to store the definition of this function into the server itself, and there are a variety of ways to test it. For both of the two demonstrated below I will be using the MongoDB Shell (which is the newer utility that replaces the previous `mongo` interface).

The first option is simply to open the shell session and paste the function in:

```
$ ./mongosh
...
> loadEducation
ReferenceError: loadEducation is not defined
test> function loadEducation() {
...         const bulkInsert = db.education.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
            ...
...         }
[Function: loadEducation]
> loadEducation
[Function: loadEducation]
>
```

The second option involves saving the function definition to a file. Here I've done so using a file named `customFile` that is saved in the current directory that my command line is in. Namely:

```
$ cat customFile
function loadEducation() {
        const bulkInsert = db.education.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
        const documents = db.summaryData.find({});

        documents.forEach(function (doc) {
            const element = {
                education: "$doc.education",
                "education_num": "$doc.education_num"
            };
            bulkInsert.find(element).upsert().replaceOne(element);
        });
        bulkInsert.execute();
        return true;
        }
$
```

The second option then is to open the shell and then use [the `load()` method](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/mongodb-shell/write-scripts/require-load-differences/):

```
$ ./mongosh
...
> loadEducation
ReferenceError: loadEducation is not defined
> load('customFile')
true
> loadEducation
[Function: loadEducation]
>
```

At this point for both options you can then simply call the function using `loadEducation()` in the shell session as expected.

Comment: OMG thank you so much!! I can't believe I could just copy and paste the whole thing into mongo shell. I have literally spent the past 2 hours on Google for this simple thing.